# Python Kafka client cannot connect to remote Kafka server

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I have an Ubuntu VM on cloud, where I downloaded Kafka version 2.8.1 from the [Official Kafka site](https://kafka.apache.org/downloads) and followed the instructions in [Kafka's official quickstart guide](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart).

I am using a python client to consume one of the topics that I created as part of the quickstart guide. When I run it on the VM, everything runs fine, however, when I run the same program on my local system, I get the below error

```
Unable connect to node with id 0: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
...
File "/Path/python3.9/site-packages/aiokafka/client.py", line 547, in check_version
   raise KafkaConnectionError(
kafka.errors.KafkaConnectionError: KafkaConnectionError: No connection to node with id 0
```

The python program I am using:

```
import asyncio
import aiokafka

async def consume(self):
    consumer = aiokafka.AIOKafkaConsumer(
        "quickstart-events", bootstrap_servers="IP:9092"
    )
    try:
        await consumer.start()
        async for msg in self.consumer:
            print(
                "consumed: ",
                msg.topic,
                msg.partition,
                msg.offset,
                msg.key,
                msg.value,
                msg.timestamp,
            )
    finally:
        await consumer.stop()

asyncio.run(consume())
```

I have ensured that the necessary ports (9022) on Ubuntu is open -
I checked that I could telnet into port 9022 from my local system.

I am not sure what could be the reason that I am unable to access Kafka over internet. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following attribute in `config/server.properties` to bootstrap server address you are using in your code.

```
advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://IP or FQDN:9092
```

Comment: They don't necessarily need to be the same in the client code, just that the bootstrap address and advertised addresses are resolvable from the client network. For example, the bootstrap address could be a single load balancer, which hits a broker, and that returns its actual remote address